# Server for Webservices

Tags: web-services, rest

I am trying to develop webservices for a data collection server. I understand the restful services part of the schema, but what does the independent data collection server have to do differently to serve data to webservices? To be clear, "Data server - Webservices - third party client" is the overall schema. When a client requests data from webservices, how does it get it from the data server? HTTP request? Data server should send HTTP responses? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 parties in the data exchange: Client, Web Service layer, and Data Server (Remote database). Generally speaking, the client would exchange the data by HTTP, or any other protocol. It is not strictly limited - but `HTTP` is the most frequent case. Next, you Web service layer would connect to the remote database. It all depends on your choice of technologies. Usually, you have specific classes to work with the remote databases such as `JDBC` `Connection` class for relational databases. When the client connects to your web service, the web service in turn calls the methods of classes, which connect to remote databases. How this happens is not the concern of the developer (it might be a binary protocol, or HTTP request - depends on the database) - you just have an API. When the response is returned to your classes, you transform it into some data format like XML, or JSON, and send it back to the client as an HTTP response, or with some other protocol.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I ask this is because I have to provide instructions as to how to implement the server so that I can build my webservices. We also do not want to talk to the remote database directly. So, I guess HTTP should be the way to go.